Seeking Advice on Triangulation Error Using GPS-Enabled Drone Images in Rerun Visualization Software
I am currently working on a project where I am triangulating a point using multiple images captured by a GPS-enabled drone. The images have been reconstructed using software such as Reality Capture and Pix4DMatic. I have successfully obtained both the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the cameras involved.
The projection error within Reality Capture and Pix4DMatic is minimal—less than a pixel—indicating that the reconstruction is highly accurate. However, when I import these parameters and use them in a visualization tool like Rerun, I encounter an issue. Specifically, the rays drawn from the same feature point across all the images do not converge at a single point, as expected. Instead, I observe an error of approximately 2-4 cm, varying slightly for each image.
To clarify, I am using undistorted images exported from Reality Capture, and therefore, no distortion parameters are required in this context.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this error might be occurring and how I might resolve it. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could there be an aspect of the process that I’m overlooking?
Thank you for your time and assistance.
-Hemanth
